# iPhone: App crashes when I click on a cell in table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk

Compiling my application works—everything is fine. The only errors I get are by deprecated functions (setText).

The only problem is now, is that when I tap on a cell in my table, the app crashes, even though it's meant to push to the next view in the stack.

Any solutions are appreciated, if you need any code, just ask.

Also, how can I only make sure that one cell goes to only one view? For example:

When I tap on CSS, it takes me to a new table with different levels of CSS. WHen I tap on an item in that new view, it comes up with an article on what I just selected.

Regards,
Jack

Here's my code at the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method:

```
   -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(indexPath.row==0){

    NextViewController *nextController = [[NextViewController alloc]
                                          initWithNibName:@"NextView" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController
                                         animated:YES];
    [nextController changeItemTable:[arryClientSide
                                     objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
}
@end
```

(as requested in the comments).

Comment: if app crashes on the cell tap the problem is likely to be in didSelectCell method - could you post it here? You can also have a look at crash log to see error description.

Comment: run application in debug mode and find exact line where your app crashes, you also should get some error message in console (menu run/console or cmd+shift+r shortcut).

Comment: Here's the error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "NextView" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

I'm assuming that it's something to do with Interface Builder

Answer (score 1):

> Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
>   reason:  -[UIViewController
>   _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "NextView" nib but the view outlet
>   was not set.'

1. Open NextView with Interface Builder
2. Set Class value at : "NextViewController" to your File's Owner [image: set files owner class]
3. Connect the View outlet (Ctrl click and drag - a blue line should appear - from the File Owner to the UIView and select "view" in options)
   [image]

Comment: Thank you. Now, I have another error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "NextView" nib but didn't get a UITableView.' I'm assuming that's something else to do with an interface builder mismatch.

Comment: Look at the doc : http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html  ---- UITableViewController must have it's tableView property set

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? I'm pretty much new to App Development, plus I'm only 14 so my use of technical jargon may be hasty in places, and I barely have much time. I try and get things in when I can.

Answer (score 1):

When we create new UIViewControllerSubClass with xib-interface, xib file is created as sourcecode.xib (can be seen in get info of that xib file): Change sourcecode.xib to "file.xib" and see the magic :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to update your code like this :

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(indexPath.row==0){

    NextViewController *nextController = [[NextViewController alloc]
                                          initWithNibName:@"NextView" bundle:nil];
    [nextController changeItemTable:[arryClientSide
                                     objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController
                                         animated:YES];
    }
else{   }
}
```

try using this code...

Comment: Is your change the 'else' clause?

Comment: With that changed, the app still quits when you tap a cell.

Answer (score 0):

Error description from comments:

> Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
>   reason: '-[UIViewController
>   _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "NextView" nib but the view outlet
>   was not set.'

If your view controller is loaded from nib file and its view is not set exception then exception is thrown. So when you create your view in IB you **must** connect view outlet to your view controller object (likely - file owner in IB).

Edit: So basically in IB in your nib file you need to do the following:
1. set file owner's type to `NextViewController`
2. connect NextViewController's view outlet to a View object

Comment: Not so sure as to what you mean. Could you direct me to where and what I'm meant to amend in my nib file? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

release that NextViewController you alloc!

```
[nextController release];
```

It's leaking.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use IB. Instead, make alloc init with nothing, then in load view:

```
self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]] autorelease];
```